# Ratiorg got statues of different sizes as a present from CodeMaster for his birthday, usnig dart

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

Example

```
For statues = [6, 2, 3, 8], the output should be
solution(statues) = 3.

Ratiorg needs statues of sizes 4, 5 and 7.
```

Input/Output

```
[execution time limit] 4 seconds (js)

[input] array.integer statues
```

An array of distinct non-negative integers.

Guaranteed constraints:

```
1 ≤ statues.length ≤ 10,
0 ≤ statues[i] ≤ 20.

[output] integer
```

The minimal number of statues that need to be added to existing statues such that it contains every integer size from an interval [L, R] (for some L, R) and no other sizes

**I want to solve my question using dart flutter**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int solution(List<int> statues) {
    statues.sort((a, b) => { return a - b });
    return statues;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int makeArrayConsecutive2(int[] statues) {
   int count = 0;
   Arrays.sort(statues);
   for(int i=1; i<statues.length; i++) {
      count += statues[i] - statues[i-1] - 1;
   }
   return count;
}
```